# ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00

Tags: 16.04, boot, boot-repair

Good day all,
My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS doesn't want to boot the system instead it hangs. When I select advance options on the GNU Grub to select an alternative image to boot from such as [Linux 4.13.0.32-generic (recovery mode)] I get the error code from title of this thread (---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00).

I tried using an external USB with the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS image to boot with it and selected "try ubuntu" and the pc boots perfectly from it. I've also attached a link of my boot info as follows:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RxXPSRGG86/

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, the VM (ubuntu 16.04.4) kernel panic frequently on a ZFS file system.

[image: ubuntu 16.04.4 kernel panic]

Comment: My solution to this was to re-install my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using from a bootable USB.